# My brother's computer's screen won't turn on until reset while running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, acer-aspire-one

My brother was waiting for something on his computer to get finished, but his monitors (including the netbook monitor) turned off and refused to turn on until he reset the computer. He was running Windows 7 and his Acer Aspire One had 1 GB of memory. Sometimes, the screen shows only a white or black colour, but doesn't turn off. This happens after my brother leaves his netbook alone after a few minutes. It does not do that on any of his Linux installations.

Comment: White usually indicates hardware problems, but if nothing is wrong under Linux, I'd suspect video card drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Download this [zip-file](http://www.mediafire.com/?9gyziga1dyenccs).

- Turn off the Acer Aspire One (AAO). If necessary leave the button pressed for a few seconds to force power
- Keep the AAO connected to the mains

In other computer:

- Prepare a USB memory formatted as "FAT" (if required format), put the latest BIOS for the AAO here, extract its contents and place the following files, `FLASHIT.EXE` and `ZG5_3310.FD` in memory USB (to file `ZG5_3310.FD`; should rename it `ZG5IA32.FD`)
- This means that you must have a FAT formatted USB stick with the files `ZG5IA32.FD` and `FLASHIT.EXE`

Now just put the memory in the AAO, and do the following:

- Hold <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> keys, and with the other hand press the Power button
- After few seconds release <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> keys and the Power button LED flashes
- After a few seconds press (again) the power button
- In moments automatically the BIOS will be flashed, the process will take about one minute, you will not see anything on the screen, and finally the AAO will automatically reboot the light of your screen back.

Comment: might be helpful to mention what's in the zip file, and to have links to the source of the files, in case there's issues with mediafire. How would flashing the bios fix the specific issue?